# How does the trigger time on Steaming Dataset works for joins

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to know how the trigger time for Streaming Dataset using join operations works for simple `inner_join`s.
As far as I understand when the query starts if no `org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.trigger()` is defined, the trigger will *trigger* as soon as possible, so I should be seeing the results as soon as possible.
I'm performing a join using 5 `Datasets`, 4 Streaming and one Static, all of them from Kakfa topics.
The topic's records are in `Avro` and `json` format (each topic has it's own format, no mixed format records).
The sink operation is writing the result on a local directory, using Parquet format.
For simplicity, I defined the `Dataset`s to read from the beginning of the topic offset, like this.

```java
//For Streaming Datasets
sparkSession.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", <local Kafka server>)
                .option("subscribe", <the subscribing topic>)
                .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .load();
//For the Static Dataset
sparkSession.read()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", <local Kafka server>)
                .option("subscribe", <the subscribing topic>)
                .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .load();
```

Then to parse the topic records I use

```java
//For json records
<dataser>.select(col("value").cast("string"))
                .map(buildKafkaJsonMessageParser(), Encoders.STRING())
                .select(col("value").as("<alias>"))
```

Where `buildKafkaJsonMessageParser` just transform the record in string and ignores the magic bytes for the schema id.

```java
//For Avro records
<dataset>.select(functions.from_avro(col("value"), joinedRecoStatusAvroSchema).as("<alias>"));
```

Where `functions.from_avro` is from the `abris` library.
Both parsers works; if I just print the topic's content they are displayed correctly.
**Here's my doubt about trigger time**
If I perform a join operation on two `Dataset`s I can see the Parquet files being written almost immediately.

```java
<left dataset>.join(
                        <right dataset>,
                        <join statement>    
                )
                .select(<left dataset>.col(<some col>), <right dataset>.col(<some col>))
                .writeStream()
                .option("checkpointLocation", <local directory checkpoint>)
                .format("parquet")
                .option("path", <local directoy to store parquet files>)
                .outputMode("append")
                .start()
                .awaitTermination();
```

I see the Paquet files being written in less than a minute.
But when I make a `join` on all my `Dataset`s the Parquet files are written after more than 30 minutes

```java
 <dataset A>.join(
                        <dataset B>,
                        <join statement>
                )
                .join(
                        <dataset C>,
                        <join statement>
                )
                .join(
                        <dataset D>,
                                <join statement>
                )
                .join(
                        <dataset D>,
                                <join statement>
                )
                .select(<references to cols>)
                .writeStream()
                .option("checkpointLocation", <local directory checkpoint>)
                .format("parquet")
                .option("path", <local directoy to store parquet files>)
                .outputMode("append")
                .start()
                .awaitTermination();
```

Parquet files are written after 30 minutes al least.
**Why does the Parquet files takes so longto be written?**